# How to check if an object's value equals <p> </p> in custom Tags in .tag file

Tags: regex, jsp, custom-tags

I am trying to create a custom tag using .tag file to check weather a value passed in attribute is equal to an html paragraph tag

```
<p> </p>
```

Here is my code

checkEmptyBody.tag

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ attribute name="pb_val"  required="true"  rtexprvalue="true" %>

 <c:if test="${pb_val eq '<p> </p>'}">

 <%-- Do some action here--%>

 </c:if>
```

Code for usage of above defined Tag
bodyAndHeadingsAndTags.jsp

```
     <c:set var="processedBody">
           <article:renderField var="inlineElement" field="body">
             <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${inlineElement.content.articleTypeName == 'picture'}">
                 <div class="inline-image">
                   <%-- Unfortunately it is not possible to get the width/height of the inline image as it is in Content Studio
                        (by dragging the corners of the image), so therefore a hardcoded version is used instead. --%>
                     <img src="${inlineElement.content.fields.alternates.value.w300.href}"
                          width="${inlineElement.content.fields.alternates.value.w300.width}"
                          height="${inlineElement.content.fields.alternates.value.w300.height}"
                          alt="${fn:trim(inlineElement.content.fields.caption)}"
                          ${not empty fn:trim(inlineElement.content.fields.caption) ? 'class="captify"' : ''}
                          title="${inlineElement.content.fields.caption}"/>
                 </div>
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise>
               <%-- do nothing!! --%>
               </c:otherwise>
             </c:choose>
           </article:renderField>
       </c:set>

      <c:out value="${processedBody}"></c:out>111111111111111

     <%-- <tgam:substring input="GOODMORNING"  start="2" end="6"/>--%>

       <tools:checkEmptyBody pb_val="${processedBody}" />

       In bdyandheading <c:out value="${processedBody}"></c:out>
```

The problem is even if the value of pb_val is

```
<p> </p>
```

, the if condition comes out to false and hence the action is not performed.

I think since the value is not a string, it's an html tag, the if condition fails.

How to test for such equality?? Do I have to use regular expression or is there some other way to do this??

Thanks

Comment: Show the use of the tag where you think the condition should be true.

Comment: Added the code for usage of the new custom tag.

Comment: Did you try `<tools:checkEmptyBody pb_val="<p> </p>" />`? Maybe `${processedBody}` has two spaces or no spaces, like `<p></p>` or `<p />`?